# How can I perform ghosting of 5 HDDs

Tags: windows, installation, windows-vista

Pls help, I have some five laptops I want to install windows vista os on, they are all hp dv 6000 and I have only one cd, is there a way I can just install on the hard drive and replicate the installation on the other four HDDs to save me time...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org), it even has a mode in which the server uses multicast to reduce bandwidth utilisation, but I'd say it's overkill for 5 computers.

Remember to [sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh824816.aspx) the base installation before cloning!

Comment: I never understood why people prefer clonezilla to F.O.G., personally.  Honestly, though, it seems to me like any Linux-based solution is going to be "too hard" for this particular use case.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: Never heard about F.O.G, do you refer to free ghost project (on SF)? I'd guess that the feature set of clonezilla is why its recommended: multicast, creation of standalone DVDs with images, support for NTFS, FAT, ext[234] are just few things I remember about it from top of my head. But yes, I have to admit that its interface is a bit hard to use.

Comment: Yeah, free open ghost.  Kind of a tangent, I guess, but back when I was doing things a few years back, (in addition to the interface sucking) the documentation for clonezilla was just awful.  Worse than awful, even.  Like, if someone handed me that as documentation for a system, I'd enroll them in an English class, punch them in the face and fire them.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: It definitely wasn't this bad when I looked at it, though I've been using it less than 2 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the answer is in your question - use Symantec's [Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/ghost-solution-suite) product, it's really easy to use.

By the way, why are you using Vista, even its replacement (Windows 7) is about to be replaced?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I use windows 7 on my own pc, it's my client's request.  I'm on it now.